# Grep from a list of strings in a file

Tags: grep

I have a list of strings in a file called `users.txt`.
For instance, this file contains a list of username separated by a new line:

```
Jhon
Paul
Mark
Harry
```

I have to grep over this list of strings in order to extract from another file (called `myLog.out`) the lines containing that usernames.

To achive my target I'm using the following command:

```
grep -wFf users.txt myLog.out > out.txt
```

Now, my `out.txt` only contains the occurrences of the last name of the `users.txt` file, that is:

```
2017-12-17 15:13:41,191 [13] INFO  it.test.Service- user: Harry
2017-12-17 15:13:41,191 [13] INFO  it.test.Service- user: Harry
2017-12-17 15:13:41,191 [13] INFO  it.test.Service- user: Harry
```

There are occurrences of Jhon and Paul in `myLog.out` file but I'm not able to retrive  them using the previous grep command.

Comment: `grep -f users.txt myLog.out > out.txt`

Comment: Check users.txt and myLog.out with `cat -A` or `cat -v` for special characters.